# How to pass data between the MainActivity and Intent.ACTION_DELETE in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Passing data from the **MainActivity** to a new activity is simple in Android:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extra", "some data");
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Then you can get some data back to the MainActivity like this:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("key", "String data"); 
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

This works for a custom activity. But how can I exchange data between the **MainActivity** and a built-in activity like `Intent.ACTION_DELETE`?

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_DELETE` isn't an activity, it's a string

Comment: Yes but its responsible for running the uninstall activity